# How to wait for two GitHub workflows?

Tags: github-actions

I have a GitHub repository with two workflows that produce three distinct Go code coverage files: workflow A gives me one file, workflow B gives me two files. They both run different tests that hit different lines of code in the same repository.

How can I

1. wait for both workflows to complete so that I can
2. combine these three files into one

and produce an accurate code coverage measurement?

Comment: An option could be to have a main workflow, calling both workflows as [reusable workflow](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/reusing-workflows), then join the files on a last job (in the main workflow) that would start only once the jobs calling reusable workflows finished, to join the files (I think you will have to save them as artifact in each reusable to use them in the main afterward).

Comment: @GuiFalourd thank you! If you post that as an answer, i'll mark it as the solution.

Comment: I'm happy it helped! I've added the suggestion as an answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could have a `main` workflow calling both workflows as [reusable workflow](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/reusing-workflows).

Then, you would join the files on a last job (in the `main` workflow) that would start only once the jobs calling reusable workflows finished. This last job would join the files.

*Observation: You will probably have to save the files as artifact in each reusable to use them in the main workflow afterward.*

**Example for the `main` workflow structure:**

```
jobs:
   job1:
     uses: .github/workflows/reusable-workflow-1.yml@ref

   job2:
     uses: .github/workflows/reusable-workflow-2.yml@ref

   job3:
     needs:
      - job1
      - job2
     runs-on: ...
     steps:
       [ ... ]
```